# Compare the occurrences of a character in each line of a text file to a number, and add more of that character according to a condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

In a bash script, I want to count the number of occurrences (n) of the character '|' (pipe) in each line of a text file that looks like this:

```
2 | bar | foo | 12-10-2020 |
1 | foo | bar | null
4 | boo | far |
```

Where we have a condition to check if (n) is less than 4, we add a '|' at the end of the line, in the example above to the second and third line, and not the first.

I know that "awk" can be used to get (n), and "sed" to edit the file, but the problem is incorporating the condition within the command and updating the text file with the new pipes at the end of the lines where necessary.

How would one go about implementing this?

Comment: Why do you think that's difficult in `awk`?

Comment: `if (n < 4) print the line with an added |`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk and the data in the file pipes:

```
awk -F\| 'NF<5 { print $0" |" } NF>=5 { print $0 }' pipes
```

Set the field delimiter to |. Check to see if the number of field are less that 5 (less than 4 pipes). If so, print the line along with an additional |, otherwise just print the line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a an `awk` script:

```
awk -F'|' 'NF<4{$0=$0"|"}1' input.file
```

#### input.file

```
2 | bar | foo | 12-10-2020
1 | foo | bar 
4 | boo | far | 2 | bar | foo
1 | foo 
4 | boo | far | 2 | bar | foo | 12-10-2020
1 | foo | bar | null
4
```

#### output

```
2 | bar | foo | 12-10-2020
1 | foo | bar |
4 | boo | far | 2 | bar | foo
1 | foo |
4 | boo | far | 2 | bar | foo | 12-10-2020
1 | foo | bar | null
4 |
```

#### script explanation

```
BEGIN {       # pre process initial variable
  FS = "|";   # set field separator to "|"
}
NF < 4 {      # for each line having less then 4 fields
  $0 = $0"|"; # append "|" at the line's end
}
{             # for every line
  print;      # print the current line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NF<5 { $0=$0" |" } 1' file
2 | bar | foo | 12-10-2020 |
1 | foo | bar | null |
4 | boo | far | |
$
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation for the solution provided by you.